# Can we make an element (div) transparent to mouse events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make an element transparent to events. If I click on it, the element just behind to it get fired that event.

Comment: what do you mean by saying `the element just behind to it`.. how is that element placed behind it?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) CSS property :

```
myElement {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Do note browser compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: will it be working in IE?

Comment: @user1598937 Only in the most recent version of IE

Comment: There is a polyfill for older IE: https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill

Comment: took me hours to eventually find this. was trying all sorts of crazy javascript interventions. upvoted!

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Set `pointer-events:none;` on the element above.

Here's a simple example: When I click on the image the select element opens:

```css
div {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    position:relative;
    top: -18px;
    left: 58px;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/14/14) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
</select>
<div></div>
```

Browser support is good ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events)): except for IE - where it is only supported in IE11

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to do it the jQuery-Way (because logic should be out of CSS) you could use `$( "#foo").unbind( "click" );`.

You can find more information here:

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/